# Does gcc provide builtin to read big endian memory?

Tags: c, gcc, endianness, built-in

I need to read/write device registers (which in my case are in big endian address space) from both little endian cores (e.g. arm). I do not want to use intermediate endian conversion routines (e.g. htonl). My understanding is that modern cores have instructions using which they can do reads/writes to big endian memory directly.

Does gcc offer any builtin for the above which automatically generates right assembly instruction(s)?

Comment: ARM is generally configurable when it comes to endianness, but are traditionally *big* endian. The x86 family is little-endian. And if there are special assembler instructions then you have to be *certain* about the CPU architecture because the instructions can differ *a lot* between architectures.

Comment: As for if GCC supports any intrinsics for endian-conversion, read [the online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are built-in functions available from GCC 4.3.0:

1. Built-in Function: int32_t __builtin_bswap32 (int32_t x), it returns the order of byes reversed. for eg. 11223344 will be 0x44332211
2. Built-in Function: int64_t __builtin_bswap64 (int64_t x)
   is also similar to __builtin_bswap32, except that it returns 64 bits.

Please refer to the [Beware the builtins](http://hardwarebug.org/2010/01/14/beware-the-builtins/).

Comment: Using __builtin_bswap32 will cost additional instructions to do byte swapping after loading the register from big endian device register. I am looking for some mechanism which can directly generate appropriate cpu instruction to load from big endian memory and store in local register (in host endianness).

Comment: @VakulGarg: which CPU instruction does that?  If there isn't a CPU instruction to do it, you can't use that which doesn't exist.  If it does exist, you can work with `asm` or whatever to gain access to the instruction.

Comment: PowerPC has lwbrx/stwbrx instructions for byte-swapping loads and stores.